# Wix Burn didn't Pass command line args to related packages (old version of same installer)

Tags: wix, wix3.7

Recently I saw an annoying behaviour with my Wix based bootstrapper. We pass a command line args to our installer like

```
myinstaller.exe /S option=10
```

I then use it in my bundle by following

```
<Variable Name="option" Value="0" bal:Overridable="yes" />
```

I was then passing it to related msi or exe packages. All was working fine and according to expectation.

I then noticed an unexpected behaviour with our app and investigate it through log to realize that Wix is not forwarding this command line args or variable to related bundle.

On same machine I executed the newer version of installer with command line args. Wix noticed the older version so it went to removing it after installing newer version but it didn't forward option to that installer. Installer use this args to decide few thing and it went on wrong path. See log for details.

```
[349C:282C][2014-05-08T20:12:24]i001: Burn v3.7.1224.0, Windows v6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1), path: G:\myinstaller.exe, cmdline: '/S option=-2'
[349C:282C][2014-05-08T20:12:24]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'option' to value '0'
.
.
.
.
[349C:282C][2014-05-08T20:12:28]i301: Applying execute package: {93df3160-1ac2-4e72-ad1b-9040001d9d58}, action: Uninstall, path: C:\Users\Test\AppData\Local\Package Cache\{93df3160-1ac2-4e72-ad1b-9040001d9d58}\myinstaller.exe, arguments: '"C:\Users\Test\AppData\Local\Package Cache\{93df3160-1ac2-4e72-ad1b-9040001d9d58}\myinstaller.exe" -uninstall -quiet -burn.related.upgrade'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have spent many hours over the internet to search any solution but I didn't able to find any. I then resolved this issue by setting a registry value, which is obviously workaround but I have to do this. I then looked at wix toolset bug list to find it is marked as bug targeting wix 4.x. Here is a link for further insight.

http://wixtoolset.org/issues/3704/